# Subsetting a List in R where not a value

Tags: r, list, subset

I'm having trouble "filtering" a list in R because I don't have specific parameters. The function i've created will evaluate 4000 html strings and "decide" if it is a valid or not address:

```
Tree<-lapply(TreeList,ValURL)
#Returns a list with "Error" or a html string in each element (about 4000 elements total).
```

I want to create a subset of the Tree list with only the elements that are NOT "Error".I'm used to SQL, so it would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Tree WHERE Column1!="Error"
```

Obviously it's different in R but I can't seem to get it. I've been trying (to no avail):

```
 Tree$"Error"
```

Help!

Comment: `SELECT * FROM Tree WHERE Column1!="Error"` translates to something like `Tree[Tree$Column1 != "Error", ]`

Comment: @RichardScriven thanks, but I don't have a "Column1" in a list in R, just a set of elements with "Error". Tried this as well:
     Tree[Tree$!="Error"]

Comment: @eflores89 this is fundamental, though perhaps hard to grasp at first, R.  You need to do some reading and learn more about subsetting, otherwise you will get nowhere.  Try Hadley's online book **[section on subsetting](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html)**.

Comment: @BrodieG Yep, been there and didn't seem to quite grasp it, sorry. I'll keep at it, thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Tree` looks kind of like this

```
Tree<-list(
    "Error",
    "<p>Hello</p>",
    "<h1>Heading</h1>",
    "Error",
    "<strong>Bold</strong"
)
```

then this should work:

```
Tree[Tree != "Error"]
```

Comment: you can just do `Tree[Tree != "Error"]` in this case, but OP still needs to do some reading...

Comment: @BrodieG Good point. I'm not used to having such simple objects in a list. I will update.